# UICollectionView cell layout not resetting previously set borders

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view which I reuse to load 2 totally different data sets based on user choice. For each data set the collection view has a different border setting.

On the initial load, the collection view cell displays correct borders, then for the consecutive loads, the previous borders are retained in the cell.

I set the borders inside this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { }
```

What I want is, on every load of the collection view, the cell's borders should also be reset.

Edit: Here is how I construct my cell and set borders:

```
cell.label.text = MATRIX[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor    

if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.addBorders(left: YES, right: NO, top: YES, bottom: NO)
}
if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
    cell.addBorders(left: YES, right: YES, top: YES, bottom: YES)
}
if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.addBorders(left: YES, right: NO, top: NO, bottom: YES)
}
if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row > 0 {
    cell.addBorders(left: YES, right: NO, top: NO, bottom: YES)
}
if indexPath.section > 1 && indexPath.row == 1 {
    cell.addBorders(left: YES, right: NO, top: NO, bottom: NO)
}
if indexPath.row == MATRIX[0].count {
    cell.addBorders(left: NO, right: YES, top: NO, bottom: NO)
}
if indexPath.section == MATRIX.count {
    cell.addBorders(left: NO, right: NO, top: NO, bottom: YES)
}
```

UICollectionViewCell extension method for adding borders:

```
func addBorders(left: Bool, right: Bool, top: Bool, bottom: Bool) {
    if left {
        self.layer.addBorder(edge: .left, thickness: 1)
    }
    if right {
        self.layer.addBorder(edge: .right, thickness: 1)
    }
    if top {
        self.layer.addBorder(edge: .top, thickness: 1)
    }
    if bottom {
        self.layer.addBorder(edge: .bottom, thickness: 1)
    }
}
```

CALayer extension method:

```
func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, thickness: CGFloat) {

    let border = CALayer()
    switch edge {
    case UIRectEdge.top:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: thickness)
        break
    case UIRectEdge.bottom:
        border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:self.frame.height - thickness, width:self.frame.width, height:thickness)
        break
    case UIRectEdge.left:
        border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: thickness, height: self.frame.height)
        break
    case UIRectEdge.right:
        border.frame = CGRect(x:self.frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height:self.frame.height)
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    self.addSublayer(border)
}
```

Comment: The code that you provided is too short. Please provide the code bit more so that it will be easier to find what your actual problem is!

Comment: post complete "cellForItemAt"  method.

Comment: you must be missing else condition

Answer (score 0):

Inside the collection view cell there is an *instance method*, called **[prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse)**:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    // make your borders nil or reset them
}
```

Comment: This is possibly good answer, but explain please how he can use this method to accomplish his goal.

Comment: When I was at my starting line of development, I asked many questions on forums and profile groups on "how can I achieve this and that" and "what's problem with my code, why it's not working". And I'm glad, that many people didn't give me a copy paste solution, but gave me a point from where I have to research it by myself. In my case, from the given description of @vasu I make a decision, that problem is with reusing cells. I gave a starting point to research, next step depends not on me

Comment: @PeteStreem thank you for this pointer, but unfortunately it isn't working perfectly. Even without adding any borders, i see borders randomly. Because of low reputation, I couldn't upload the sample image :(

Comment: @Vasu you can upload your code to github and we can take a look ;) Or maybe update your question with more lines of code so we can see what exactly is wrong

Comment: @PeteStreem sure. but what i noticed is, even if i don't give any borders for any of the cells, and even if i don't reload the collection view, some cells tend to have some borders. when the background was white, it was unnoticed. when i set the background color, the margins are visible.

Answer (score 0):

First Declare a Global Variable like

```
var flagForBoarder = 1
```

Then you check in collection view cellforItemAt

```
if flagForBoarder == 1
{
cell.view.layer.boarderColor = UIcolor.red.cgcolor
}
else
{
cell.view.layer.boarderColor = UIcolor.blue.cgcolor
}
```

set the FlagForBoarder value  when you tap on button or reload collectionview

```
flagForBoarder = 2
```

Comment: Unrelated but variable names should use lower camel case in Swift.

Comment: Could you please tell me, what is that cell.view you are referring to?

Comment: @Vasu that view is inside the cell

Answer (score 0):

try using two custom `UICollectionViewCell` for two different data set

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == gamePad{
        var cell: UICollectionViewCell?
        cell = gamePad.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "coloredCell", for: indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        cell?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.frame.height)!/2
        return cell!
    }
    if collectionView == blackCounterCV {
       let cell = blackCounterCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "blackC", for: indexPath) as! BlackCCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.frame.height)/2
        cell.blackLbl.text = "TEST"
        return cell
    }       
     return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the code I have, except, instead of corder radius I add borders to the layers. But it adds both the borders on consecutive loads.